# Opening and closing UINavigationController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I know it was probably written somewhere about this problem already but I just can't find the solution and am on the problem already for a few days.

I have an application with UITabbar with 4 UINavigationControllers.
On one of this UINavigationControllers there is a UIViewController with a button that opens with modal transition another UINavigationController. On opening everything works normal, but after closing last NC from its UIViewController with code:

```
self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
```

or

```
self.navigationController?.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
```

I get a problem.
Whatever the next thing I do, I get a warning **Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for** and on UIViewControllers methods viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear don't get called. But just to make it clear, I don't get this problem only when I open a new view, I also get it if I just switch between tabs to other UINavigationViewController.

I have checked one of the possibilities that I've read about and I' sure that I don't open one thing twice.

I just can't figure out if it is the problem of multiple NavigationControllers or the way I close it or what.

Any suggestion will be helpful.

EDIT1:

Forgot to tell, that the UINavigationController is opened with modal segue, not by code.

All the NC have at least one VC (all 4 on the tabbar and also the one opened later)

EDIT2:

The code that dismisses the VC is run on the last opened VC on last opened NC (not one of the tabbar NC) to return to one of the tabbar NC/ his VC.
To make sure I'll try to write it again

```
TC -> NC    NC    NC    NC
      |     |     |     |
      VC    VC    VC    VC
       |
      NC
       |
      VC - the one that calls dismiss to return to previous VC
```

It is just so frustrating that until I open another UINavigationController everything works great, but after that the problem begins. Or too add another thing I noticed, the problem appears after modal presenting another controller, it doesn't matter if it is a UINavigation or just normal ViewController.

EDIT3:

Thanks to @kgkoutio the problem was solved, the mistake I made was that I did't call super.viewDidLoad and super.viewWillAppear somewhere. After adding it to all of VC the problem disappeared.

Again big thanks to @kgkoutio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code dismisses the NC not the VC. When the app is started the TabBar is initialized with the set of your Navigation controllers. Consider dismissing the UIViewController instead of NC:

```
self.navigationController.topViewController?.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Comment: unfortunately still the warning but thanks for the suggestion or do you think I should dismiss first the VC and then the NC?

Also all the NC have at least one VC

Comment: Once you dismiss the NC the VC is dismissed with that. However, UITabBar  once it is created has a collection with all the View controllers (in your case Navigation Controllers). Once you dismiss one it will be nil so I guess the system can not run any VC functions. You might need to share more about where you run the code that dismisses the code.

Comment: Is there any chance that when you try to dismiss  the NC or VC an animation is running? This might explain the warning. Try to add the dismiss code in a dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        [self.navigationController.topViewController?.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)

});

Comment: Is there a way to check that beside looking at the code?

Comment: Sorry check out my editing above... I accidentally posted before I wrote the code :(

Comment: Tried calling this, but still the same  

DispatchQueue.main.async { [unowned self] in
            self.navigationController?.topViewController?.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
        }

Comment: Could it be that there is just to much stuff on the NC and TC to be working properly?

Just don't understand why there is no problem before I open the extra NC

Comment: make sure you call the super classes implementation of viewWillAppear and viewDidLoad in all the Vc

Comment: It looks like you saved my day/week, I just cant believe that this was the problem, well at least as it looks for now. Will do some big testing now but that is what it looks like. Thanks big time